# How to create 3 subfloat (a) (b) (c) for 1 figure?

Tags: floats

I have a script that generates a figure

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{example-image-a}}
\caption{}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

However, I would like to have

> (a) text <manual spacing> (b) text <manual spacing> (c) text

How can I achieve this? For example, something like `\subfloat[][][]{\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{example-image-a}}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by adding `(a) text <manual spacing> (b) text <manual spacing> (c) text` into the figure itself so now I can have 1 figure with 3 captions.

Comment: Your answer can't be helpful to anyone. Please  extend it to MWE, which produce what you after. To my opinion @Elyo answer (+1) is far better and consistent.

Answer (score 2):

```
\begin{figure}
     \centering
     \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
         \centering
         \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{graph1}
         \caption{$y=x$}
         \label{fig:y equals x}
     \end{subfigure}
     \hfill
     \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
         \centering
         \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{graph2}
         \caption{$y=3sinx$}
         \label{fig:three sin x}
     \end{subfigure}
     \hfill
     \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
         \centering
         \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{graph3}
         \caption{$y=5/x$}
         \label{fig:five over x}
     \end{subfigure}
        \caption{Three simple graphs}
        \label{fig:three graphs}
\end{figure}
```

**Result**

[image: Result]

Taken from [Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex./How_to_Write_a_Thesis_in_LaTeX_(Part_3)%3A_Figures%2C_Subfigures_and_Tables)

Comment: that is 3 captions for 3 figures not 1

Comment: but you said you wanted something like `(a) text <manual spacing> (b) text <manual spacing> (c) text`.